# Select element with Xpath by attribute value with character wildcard

Tags: html, xpath, xquery

I'm trying to learn xpath, and I can't seem to find any results of anyone getting element by with character wildcards. I'm not sure if or how this is possible?

**example**

```
<tr>
    <th class="textLeft textTop">Opgavebeskrivelse:</th>
    <td>                            
        <a id="m_Content_opgaverDS_abc" href="/about">click me</a> <br>         
        <a id="m_Content_opgaverDS_123" href="/other_stuff">click me too</a><br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to get both `<a>`-elements by searching for the `id`. But since they are not exactly equal, I want to use a character wildcard, something like:

```
//*[@id='m_Content_opgaverDS*']
```

but this doesn't find any elements. And this

```
//*[contains(@id, 'm_Content_opgaverDS')]
```

only finds the first element. I need both :'(

**Edit:**

I use the Javascript console in the safari browser for Mac to test the Xpaths. I'm going to implement these Xpaths into a iOS app the uses the safari browser to scrape some websites.

I've declared this function in the browser:

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
```

and then evaluate the path like so: `getElementByXpath("//a[starts-with(@id, 'm_Content_opgaverDS')]")`

But if I remove the `.singleNodeValue` part, I get an error:

> TYPE_ERR (DOM XPath Exception 52): The expression could not be
>   converted to return the specified type.

Comment: Your second XPath expression is correct - and should return both results. What tool is only giving you the one result?

Comment: My guess is you're probably using this expression in an XSLT 1.0 xsl:value-of instruction, which discards all selected nodes except the first. But of course that's a wild guess because you haven't given us full information.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
//a[starts-with(@id, "m_Content_opgaverDS")]
```

Check [function starts-with()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with)

Like the function name, it select nodes `a` with `@id` starting with second argument

`Edit`: I get both `//a`

Comment: Your answer is similar to `//*[contains(@id, 'm_Content_opgaverDS')]` which he says that it only returns one item. (I know your answer is correct, but it will not help him).

Comment: @zx485 that's right. It still only return the first element. How come we have different results?